# Specify the number of pattern repeats in JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I used regex in `C#` and there is a way to specify the number of repeats for any pattern:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]{3, 15}
```

The regex above will check that pattern `[0-9a-zA-Z]` will repeat from 3 to 15 times. When I try to do the same in `JavaScript`, it does not work:

```
var regex = new RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z]{3, 15}");
regex.test("myusername"); // this should return true
```

How can I do this with JavaScript regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the space between braces; i.e., use `[0-9a-zA-Z]{3,15}`. This should work. :)

Answer (score 1):

first drop space between brackets and then insert / at the first and end of pattern, like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("/[0-9a-zA-Z]{3,15}/$");
regex.test("myusername"); // this should return true
```